# Websockets and Chrome DevTools

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I have two questions about websockets and how they are presented in Chrome DevTools. If that helps, I am using SockJS and StompJS on top of it. Spring framework on the backend.

[image]

1. What do those symbols `o`, `a` and `h` represent?
2. After being disconnected from the websocket, I got a message from the server (the last line in the picture attached). I did not expect that. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are from SockJS communication protocol. You can see them in the SockJS client code here: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/blob/main/lib/main.js#L244

- o: open connection
- h: heartbeat
- a: array of messages
- m: single message
- c: close connection